# how to know the number of filters in deep learning models and see every filter's output?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filter, deep-learning

I tried to know the number of filters, map to see the output of every filter in order to observe which filter is good for certain color and texture of clothes.
I found this idea used in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921889019302891) paper for color.

If you have any idea or suggestion, please write it.

My purpose is to extract color and texture of cloths for every person.

Full code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
# import cupy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2

global out

out = cv2.VideoWriter('outpy.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 3, (640, 480))

# load our serialized model from disk
print("[INFO] loading model...")

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('prototxt.txt', 'caffemodel')  # deep neural network ( dnn )

# initialize the video stream, allow the cammera sensor to warmup,
# and initialize the FPS counter
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
# vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()           #change  vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vs.release()
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()

# loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels
    ret, frame = vs.read()  # add ret,
    #     frame = vs.read()
    # frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    # grab the frame dimensions and convert it to a blob
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)),
                                 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
    # predictions
    net.setInput(blob)
    # detections = net.forward()
    detections = np.array(net.forward())
    big_area = 0
    big_center = 320
    detected = 0
    fps.update()
    fps.stop()
    # loop over the detections

    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
        # the prediction
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        object_type = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])

        #           confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]   

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if object_type == 15 and confidence > 0.2:  # it was if confidence > args["confidence"]:

            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            #            print (w,h)


            # draw the prediction on the frame
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format('person', float(confidence) * 100)
            text1 = " ssd_CPU: ({:.2f} FPS,  {:.2f} sec.)".format(fps.fps(), fps.elapsed())

            #                label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format('person',confidence * 100)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), [0, 0, 255], 2)
            y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
            cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, [0, 0, 255], 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, text1, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, [0, 0, 255], 3)
            y0 = startY + ((endX - startX) / 3.2)



    out.write(frame)
    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    # update the FPS counter
    fps.update()

    # stop the timer and display FPS information
    fps.stop()
    print("[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
    print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

# do a bit of cleanup
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

data[caffemodel, prototxt.txt](https://github.com/jakelarsen17/TurtleBot-Follow-Person)

please help me or any suggestions

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please do a deeper search for "visualization tools" in your paradigm.

Comment: Thanks, @Prune. Could you give me some tips, please?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  "any suggestions" and "give me some tips" are out of scope.